# SuperUser tags: [nas] vs [network-attached-storage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I've asked a couple questions on SuperUser that I originally tagged with [[nas]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nas). There were a few other questions out there with that tag already. After awhile, one of my questions got the [[network-attached-storage]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-attached-storage) tag added. It looks like three of the questions in [network-attached-storage] are already tagged as [nas]. Should we try to standardize on one to prevent some fragmentation?

EDIT: I retagged the five items:

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-attached-storage

Answer (score 8):

Yes, definitely.

The big question is, which of the two alternatives to use. I prefer [NAS], because it's shorter; and I would not search for [network-attached-storage] when it's so much easier to just type three letters. 
But others might disagree with me.

Anyway, the community needs people who put effort into keeping the tag system clean. It does not organise by itself, unfortunately...

Comment: I think that NAS is pretty much an accepted standard in the industry. Expanding it would be like, expanding the [sata] and [atx] tags.

Comment: Good      point!

Comment: I agree with both of you (Treb and jason) and would vote you up multiple times if I could.

Comment: I retagged the five items: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-attached-storage

Answer (score 4):

NAS may be similar to Serverfault users, but I think it may be hard to unserstand for SU useres, who are just "typical users on steroids". How many sysadmins will know what RTTI, BDE or IBX is? These are acronyms from Delphi world, and may be not understood by people from outside SO-world (ie: not developers). Since every domain has got it's own acronyms, I do not think we should present users with unfamiliar acronyms.