# Make [network-attached-storage] a synonym of [nas]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Can [network-attached-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-attached-storage) be added as a tag synonym for the [nas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nas) tag?
Currently, when typing the full name of **NAS** in the tags field, which is **[Network-attached storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)**, you don't get any tag suggestions.

Comment: There are no questions under [tag:network-attached-storage] anyway... but I guess a synonym would be proper.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Because [network-attached-storage] [no longer exists](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/383/superuser-tags-nas-vs-network-attached-storage?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created the synonym for you.